# Is possible to change msiexec return code

Tags: windows-installer

I launch msiexec at a process, also I use ::GetExitCodeProcess to get return code. The question is can I use some way to change this return code? I want the return code always 0 no matter what the msiexec command line is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change msiexec exit code.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can change the exit code of the msiexec. However, you can try to ignore the return code in the calling code (whatever it is).

Answer (score 0):

You can't control other process exit code. It is the process that decides which code it returns by calling [`ExitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658.aspx) function.

Yet you can ignore its exit code.
If you don't care for exit code, you can safely ignore it and even remove the call to [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189.aspx) from your code.